# What signal does x button in messageBar emmit or how to get rid of it using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm creating QGIS plugin and I'm informing user about the progress of computation via QProgressBar, that is shown in messageBar. I have added Cancel button, that gives user a possibility to end the computation (it shows QMessageBox with question whether the user wants to end computation or not). I'd like to implement the same functionality as Cancel button to x button, that is created automatically as part of messageBar or completely erase it, so there will be only Cancel button.

Does anybody have an idea how to get rid of x button or what signal is emitted, when it is clicked? I found one signal in QObject class - [destroyed](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed), but if I understand it correctly from the documentation, the process of destroying QObject cannot be stopped this way.

For illustration, my code looks like this:

```
def progressBar(self):
    """Initializing progress bar.
        """
    self.progressMessageBar = iface.messageBar().createMessage(u"Ground Radiation Monitoring:",u" Computing...")
    self.progress = QProgressBar()
    self.progress.setMaximum(100)
    self.progress.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter)

    self.cancelButton = QtGui.QPushButton()
    self.cancelButton.setText('Cancel')
    self.progressMessageBar.layout().addWidget(self.cancelButton)
    self.progressMessageBar.layout().addWidget(self.progress)
    self.iface.messageBar().pushWidget(self.progressMessageBar, iface.messageBar().INFO)

    self.cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.onCancelButton)
```

And messageBar:

[image: messageBar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `x` is a [QToolButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtoolbutton.html) which we can identify from the message bar as it's the only QToolButton present. And instead of destroying it, we could just hide it:

```
def progressBar(self):
    """Initializing progress bar.
        """
    self.progressMessageBar = iface.messageBar().createMessage(u"Ground Radiation Monitoring:",u" Computing...")
    self.progress = QProgressBar()
    self.progress.setMaximum(100)
    self.progress.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter)

    self.cancelButton = QtGui.QPushButton()
    self.cancelButton.setText('Cancel')
    self.progressMessageBar.layout().addWidget(self.cancelButton)
    self.progressMessageBar.layout().addWidget(self.progress)

    # Let's give the messageBar() a name
    msgBar = self.iface.messageBar()
    msgBar.pushWidget(progressMessageBar, iface.messageBar().INFO)
    # Now we can find the x button which is the only QToolButton in the messageBar()
    # and hide it
    msgBar.findChildren(QToolButton)[0].setHidden(True)

    self.cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.onCancelButton)
```

---

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: @pandaActive - Most welcome! Glad it worked :)